# What is the recent solution to deal with screen tearing on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I'm using the latest version of AMD proprietary driver. When I move any window, it is tearing. There are lots of thread and solutions about this issue. Some of them is out of date. As you know, tear-free desktop feature is disabled in AMDCCC. I tried the following command. However it did not work. 
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-u32=DDX,EnableTearFreeDesktop,1

Is there any recent solution to this problem? How can I enable tear-free desktop feature? Thank you.